# Shell Script: Exit call not working on using back quotes

Tags: bash, shell

I am using `exit 1` to stop a shell script execution when error occured.

**Shell Script**

```
    test() {
    mod=$(($1 % 10))
    if [ "$mod" = "0" ]
    then
        echo "$i";
        exit 1;
    fi
}


for i in `seq 100`
do
    val=`test "$i"`
    echo "$val"
done

echo "It's still running"
```

Why it's not working?. How can I stop the shell script execution?

Comment: shouldn;t this if [ "$mod" = "0" ] be if [ "$mod" -eq "0" ]

Comment: @Satya, It's not a problem. It goes inside a if condition.

Comment: it will go but as the condition is never met it will not stop execution , Could you please try changing and then see

Comment: I don't think using `test()` as a function name is the best choice - it may work due to the shell's particular preference between functions, builtins and internal commands, but it's just going to be confusing for the unwary maintainers down the road...

Answer (score 2):

The shell that `exit` is exiting is the one started by the command substitution, not the shell that starts the command substitution.

Try this:

```
for i in `seq 100`
do
    val=`test "$i"` || exit
    echo "$val"
done

echo "It's still running"
```

You need to explicitly check the exit code of the command substitution (which is passed through by the variable assignment) and call exit again if it is non-zero.

---

Incidentally, you probably want to use `return` in a function rather than `exit`. Let the function caller decide what to do, unless the error is so severe that there is no logical alternative to exiting the shell:

```
test () {
    if (( $1 % 10 == 0 )); then
        echo "$i"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `exit` command terminates only the (sub)shell in which it is executed.
If you want to terminate the entire script, you have to check the exit status
(`$?`) of the function and react accordingly:

```
#!/bin/bash

test() {
    mod=$(($1 % 10))
    if [ "$mod" -eq "0" ]
    then
        echo "$i";
        exit 1;
    fi
}


for i in `seq 100`
do
    val=`test "$i"`
    if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
    then
      exit 1;
    fi
    echo "$val"
done

echo "It's still running"
```